# My Entity Framework query always returns "1"

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, caching

This is my full code

```
var SearchValue = dbContext.TimeSheetDetails
                      .Where(t => t.StartDate == date && 
                                  t.CreatedBy == userId && 
                                  t.ManageTask.ProjectId == projectId)
                      .ToList()
                      .Select(x =>
                              new TimeSheetModel()
                              {
                                  TaskId = Convert.ToInt32(x.TaskId),
                                  EndDate = x.EndDate,
                                  EndTime = x.EndTime,
                                  Remarks = x.Remarks,
                                  StartDate = x.StartDate,
                                  StartTime = x.StartTime,
                                  Status = Convert.ToInt32(x.StatusType.StatusTypeId),
                                  StatusName = Convert.ToString(x.StatusType.StatusTypeName),
                                  TimeSheetId = x.TimeSheetId,
                                  TotalHours = x.TotalHours,
                                  CreatedBy = Convert.ToInt32(x.CreatedBy),
                                  Description = x.Description,
                                  TaskName = dbContext.TaskDetails.ToList().Where(t => t.TaskId == Convert.ToInt32(x.TaskId)).FirstOrDefault().TaskName
                              }).ToList();
```

Everything get correct data, but `TaskName` is always set to "1". Does not get the correct name.

See this line

```
TaskName = dbContext.TaskDetails
                    .ToList()
                    .Where(t => t.TaskId == Convert.ToInt32(x.TaskId))
                    .FirstOrDefault().TaskName
```

This above query always returns a "1", I don't know what the issue is.

You can see the result in quick watch. See the below image

[image]

### Update

Also i have tried this query instead of my above query

```
TaskName = x.ManageTask.TaskDetails.FirstOrDefault(t => t.TaskId == Convert.ToInt32(x.TaskId)).TaskName
```

But no luck, it's does not working, same as return "1"

Comment: You're using the `.ToList()` way too many times!

Comment: Oops, can you customize my query? if i remove the tolist(), then my problem will solved?

Comment: does your TimeSheetDetails class have a foreign key to TaskDetails? If so you should have a virtual TaskDetail property that you can reference instead of doing a manual lookup.

Comment: I have update my question, i also tried that. but not working.

Comment: @marc_s and #Brino hey guy's i agree you, but also that way's not working for me

Comment: @Brino, Please see my updated question, i have structured few days :(

Comment: Are you sure your fields are correct? You are matching TaskId in both tables and perhaps you have a field like TaskDetailsId that you should be using?

Comment: @sgmoore , Yes, that should be using, because the TaskId is getting well, but task name only not getting

Comment: What I'm confused about - the screenshot (really hard to read!) actually **DOES** show that `TaskName` in that entry **IS** in fact `1` - so what exactly are you expecting?? If that's the value - it'll be returned ....

Comment: Check the primary key of `TaskDetails`. I bet EF has wrong primary key field(s).

Comment: If you create a temporary query that returns all columns from TaskDetail instead of returning just TaskName. This will allow you to see exactly which TaskDetail record is found and you can check that TaskID is correct.

Comment: Check data in DB. Probably `TaskName` has value `1`. It is also possible that you've mapped `TaskName` property to column with other name.

Comment: @RameshRajendran it has been a long time since you dealt with this issue but I'm facing a very similar problem. Would you remember how you solved it? Thanks for any help you are able to provide.